# Heroku Sendgrid Addon Change my email links

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, smtp, sendgrid

Link which produce

```
<p><a href="http://reminderstartup.herokuapp.com/users/password/edit?reset_password_token=5C3f5rgHRzWHLUtxFtxz">Change my password</a></p>
```

But when I click on `Change my password` link in email the link becomes

```
https://u2858746.ct.sendgrid.net/wf/click?upn=YfG4z3DMomhPClWHoVkvaQYP29XK34UuZsI2MD4LGfQfCCGsKtNitHQIiF-2BVJRM6A-2BA3oXMOgFISoWaVK1-2FBwJA0c-2BpIdpyGeu9-2B8lOyLJ3j5fGn58LiXLplD95tL0gmg2tHU-2BRRS4TQnCUDPvOpFA-3D-3D_EZclTSjtHHRaG4PloSzwj6HRShsbC9zBlGwD2Lm7Vzgola8ZXXnOo8c7oqtU3BRljuKgfQ1-2BdlY0AVnjxsPGZhzinGzifKfIxq4X6Hl5SdpyH58EJIEuft55LSPM9fmL9QpPAQWKdYjt9zEgOSOETJ6VH4LonORpvppNNMW3YeuUI0z7vveBv0KyFoU2-2Ft5-2B0j6HTFlcpsQHcpNpgxZwJZQedYGr6M544I04EqZOYGM-3D
```

And it gives no data recieved error

Comment: This link should redirect you to the original link. He provide the tracking functionality on Sendgrid.

Comment: @FlorianB can you help me where is the tracking functionality button on dashboard?

Comment: Informations about tracking is located [here](https://sendgrid.com/docs/User_Guide/Settings/tracking.html). I'm not sure about capacity to use original link.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because SendGrid overrides all links to enable *click tracking* features. It then provides you with analytics, such as click through rates, etc.

There is an option to disable this feature. Login to your SendGrid dashboard and disable "Click tracking". But, I would leave it on. It's good to know what's happening, etc. (Unless that's not covered in your terms of service or user agreement).

Comment: But why the link not working if tracking features is on?

Comment: Something is wrong with the `https://sendgrid.net/` domain. I guess SendGrid servers are facing issues right now.

Comment: Yes! They are [having problems](https://twitter.com/sendgrid_ops/status/726779369394294784).